# Cannot pass the apiClient instance to another class with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to load the Google calendar API which comes in PHP, but firstly to load the API, I need to pass the `apiClient` class instance to another class, I'm having no success at this since I'm using Codeigniter to load the `apiClient` library, but it fails to load the second class.

What I've done:

```
$this->load->library('google/apiClient', NULL, 'apiClient');

echo gettype($this->apiClient); // object

// This class needs the `apiClient` class to be passed to this, but fails
$this->load->library('google/contrib/apiCalendarService', $this->apiClient);
```

The error that gets thrown is this:

> Argument 1 passed to apiCalendarService::__construct() must be an instance of apiClient, none given

However, if I do this:

```
$this->load->library('google/contrib/apiCalendarService', array($this->apiClient));
```

It will throw this error (passed the `$this->apiClient` in an array):

> Argument 1 passed to apiCalendarService::__construct() must be an instance of apiClient, array given

What is the problem here? How can I specifically pass the `apiClient` to the `apiCalendarService` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that CodeIgniter expects an array as the first parameter passed to all libraries, so not all classes fit in by default as CI libraries (particularly, ones that expect constructor parameters).

I see two options here:

1. Load the darned thing the "old way":  `include` the class and instantiate `new apiCalendarService($this->apiClient)`
2. Create a wrapper class to "bridge the gap" between the two incompatible frameworks

Option #1 is two lines of code, by the way.